# Finding the recurrence relation for greedy algorithm to find cardinality of maximum independent set of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have the following recursive algorithm in pseudocode to find the cardinality of the maximum independent set of a graph G:

def MIS(G):
max_node = node in G with maximum degree
degree01 = list(nodes in G with degree 0 or 1)

```
if G.number_of_nodes == 0:
    return 0

if len(degree01) != 0:
    node = degree01[0]
    return 1 + MIS(G.remove_nodes(node & node.neighbors))

if len(degree01)==0 and max_node.degree > 2:
    v_inc = 1 + MIS(G.remove_nodes(max_node & max_node.neighbors)
    v_exc = MIS(G.remove_nodes(max_node))
    return max(v_inc, v_exc)

if len(degree01) == 0 and max_node.degree == 2:
    connected_components = list(all connected components of G)
    sum = 0
    for components in connected_components:
        sum = sum + floor(components.number_of_nodes / 2)
    return sum
```

Base case is when the graph is empty or the graph only contains nodes of degree 2. I am trying to find time complexity of this algorithm but am struggling to determine what I should write as the recurrence relation T(n).

Let n_i be the number of nodes in the graph G with degree i. I tried to write the appropriate recurrence relation for the case where the input graph G has at most nodes with degree 4. So in this case n = n_0 + n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4. But I am not sure if this recurrence relation is correct or how to find time complexity from it.

[Here is the recurrence relation I tried to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woMkd.png)